# application(:open:options:)' nearly matches optional requirement

Tags: swift, appdelegate

Trying to open the app from outside. This is the only part that I am missing:

> Instance method 'application(*:open:options:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'application(*:open:options:)' of protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'

in my App Delegate.

There are 2 suggested fixes to silence the warning:

Mark the method as private
Add @nonobjc to the method
Doing either silence the warning. But why does this need to be done?

My code:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    let message = url.query?.removingPercentEncoding
    print(message)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the actual code causing the issue. However, it seems like you made a typo in one of the `UIApplicationDelegate` function's definitions/type signature, hence the issue.

Comment: I will add the code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace your function with this function:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, 
                 open url: URL, 
                 options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool
```

Comment: I’ll try and let you know :)

Comment: The warning was due to 'public' that another developer added to the appDelegate class, so I had to either add the public verb or remove it from the class declaration. thamks